# Building a vue app with an undefined function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I would like to build app with an undefined function.
For example, I have on a production server a function __doPostBack which I run from a vue app like this:

```
getLabel(templateName) {
__doPostBack(templateName, "");
}
```

This function I want to run from a vue after building and deploying to production server.

Can I to build a vue app ignoring that a function is undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [try-catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statement and you'll good to go. The `try-catch` will not let the process stop.

```
getLabel(templateName) {
 try {
   __doPostBack(templateName, "");
 } catch (error) {
   console.log(error)
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed disable prettier formater by /* eslint-disable */ too.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if `__doPostBack` exists before trying to run it:

```js
getLabel(templateName) {
  if (__doPostBack) {
    __doPostBack(templateName, "");
  }
}
```